# Opencv - Support Vector Machine (regression) giving out the same value always

Tags: c++, opencv, regression, svm

Can someone help me to check whether I have set the following parameter values properly ?

This is for regression using Support Vector Machine. Implementation is done in C++/OpenCV.

It gives me the same value for all the predictions. There are little differences.
For example, 5.789,5.781,5.789,5.789 , 5.034 etc.

CvSVMParams param = CvSVMParams();

```
param.svm_type = CvSVM::NU_SVR;
param.kernel_type = CvSVM::RBF; //CvSVM::RBF, CvSVM::LINEAR ...
param.degree = 0; // for poly
param.gamma = 20; // for poly/rbf/sigmoid
param.coef0 = 0; // for poly/sigmoid

param.C = 7; // for CV_SVM_C_SVC, CV_SVM_EPS_SVR and CV_SVM_NU_SVR
param.nu = 0.1; // for CV_SVM_NU_SVC, CV_SVM_ONE_CLASS, and CV_SVM_NU_SVR
param.p = 0.0; // for CV_SVM_EPS_SVR

param.class_weights = NULL; // for CV_SVM_C_SVC
param.term_crit.type = CV_TERMCRIT_ITER +CV_TERMCRIT_EPS;
param.term_crit.max_iter = 100;
param.term_crit.epsilon = 1e-6;
```

EDIT****************************************
The predictions should only be in the range from 1 to 10.

anyone knows how to set it ?

---